# Get IIS logs out of AWS elastic beanstalk into Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, filebeat

I want to get my IIS logs off my AWS elastic beanstalk windows web server instances and into Elasticsearch.

From what I've read it appears that the easiest thing is to use filebeat for this.

I can find plenty of examples of .ebextensions to set up filebeat in linux but none in windows.  All the setup in windows examples seem to start with Step 1: download and install filebeat.  I'm thinking I could probably use invoke-webrequest to get filebeat on startup but if someone already has a working .ebextensions that starts filebeat or a better way to achieve what I want then that would be great.